# Over torquing two different materials

Tags: automotive-engineering, manufacturing-engineering

What happens when you over torque a joint comprising of two different materials ? Will the corresponding material wear make the joint leak proof ?

Answer (score 1):

No, not necessarily - one material could deform sufficiently to make the joint leak as the clamping force may be reduced or non-existent.

A better answer may be possible if you gave more detail - materials, shape of joint, clamping method etc

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the materials. The materials may bind, sealing the joint tightly, or not - one deforming elastically in some places, plastically in others, and as soon as the torque is removed, the elastic deformation areas push back, producing extra gaps in the plastic deformation zones. You would produce a tight seal in most cases if you never remove the torque, keeping the joint stressed... on the other hand, the long-term stress may cause deformations or even fractures in weaker materials completely independently from the seal.